# How to get the rest of the Pattern using any linux command?

Tags: linux, awk

I am try to update a file and doing some transformation using any linux tool.

For example, here I am trying with `awk`.

Would be great to know how to get the rest of the pattern?

```
awk -F '/' '{print $1"/raw"$2}' <<< "string1/string2/string3/string4/string5"
string1,rawstring2
```

here I dont know how many "/" is there and I want to get the output:

```
string1/rawstring2/string3/string4/string5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '{ $2 = "raw" $2 } 1' <<< "string1/string2/string3/string4/string5"
```

Just modify the desired field, and print out the changed line (Have to set `OFS` so it uses a slash instead of a space to separate fields on output, and a pattern of `1` uses the default action of printing `$0`. It's an idiom you'll see a lot of with `awk`.)

Answer (score 0):

Also possible with sed:

```
sed -E 's|([^/]*/)|\1raw|' <<< "string1/string2/string3/string4/string5"
```

The `\1` in the replacement string reproduces the bit inside parenthesis and appends `raw` to it.

Equivalent to

```
sed 's|\([^/]*/\)|\1raw|' <<< "string1/string2/string3/string4/string5"
```